# How to add side_effect to original result of a function with mocker in pytest

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

I'm trying to apply side_effect function to the original result of function in mocker.
Example:

```py
# Source
def otherfnc():
    return 5


def fnc():
    value = otherfnc()  # wanted: 5 without side_effect, 6 otherwise
    return str(value)    

# Tests
def modify(data):
    return data + 1


def test_fnc():
    mocker.patch('app.path.otherfnc', side_effect=modify)
    result = fnc()
    assert result == "6"
```

Problem is the `.patch` replaces original result of `otherfnc` with MagicMock and side_effect doesn't receive expected arguments. How can I force (or create some fixture/helper function) mocker.patch to return the function value and then apply this result to the side_effect function?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using a Lambda function to wrap the original otherfnc function, then patching the resulting lambda with the desired side-effect.

**example:**

```py
def test_fnc(mocker):
    mocker.patch('app.path.otherfnc', side_effect=lambda: modify(otherfnc()))
    result = fnc()
    assert result == '6'
```

Comment: Sure, but it still forces me to call function explicitly where some of the mocks are not as simple and with this approach require call to the function we are patching... so there's a little difference between this and just using `return_value=modify(otherfnc())`. I don't want to call otherfnc() if possible

Comment: ```python
def test_fnc(mocker):
    # Use the `call` method of MagicMock to define a function that returns the original result of the stubbed function.
    value = mocker.MagicMock(return_value=otherfnc())

    # Use the patch method of the mocker fixture to substitute `app.path.otherfnc` with the value.
    mocker.patch('app.path.otherfnc', new=value)

    mocker.patch.object(value, 'side_effect', modify)

    result = fnc()
    assert result == "6"
```
check this